# Method Output in Admin Detail-View

Tags: django, django-admin

Is there an easy way of displaying method output in Djangos admin detail view? For the list view we have the **list_display** field, however i cannot find anything similar for the detail view. Of course, editing the template would be a way but isnt there something easier?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new template isn't that hard.  I typically put info in a right column like this:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% block coltype %}colMS{% endblock %}
{% block content %}{{block.super}}
<div id="content-related">
    {{original.method}}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```